# Is it possible to have xml-land resource folder?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-resources

I am developing a custom keyboard. My keyboard characters are defined in xml files in"xml" resource folder. I want to have deferent keyboards for different devices and different orientations.

Is it possible to have resource folders like xml-land, xml-xlarge and…?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible for all of your resource folders. Look at [this reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) and the following sample link:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/frameworks/base/core/res/res/xml-land/password_kbd_qwerty.xml

Answer (score -1):

yes it possible to have xml files for landscape mode.As for example you have main.xml in layout folder and you can also have the same for landscape mode.

Create **layout-land** folder under res folder and add file **main.xml** in it.During portrait mode main.xml of layout folder will be called and during landscape mode main.xml of layout-land folder will be called.

But make sure to give name of the xml file same as that of in portrait mode since same is going to be referred but for different modes.

Comment: The original question was about the **xml** folder, not **layout** folder.